# In Grafana, how to transform data format from date to week number

Tags: date, grafana, week-number

I am using [Simple Json](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource/) to get the table or series data.

Is there a way to transform the date format in the grafana from date to only the week of the day. After that, I can group by the week number to summary the week statistics.